# Using ogr2ogr to convert all shapefiles in directory?

Tags: shapefile, mapinfo, convert, ogr2ogr

I have a directory with several shapefiles.

How can convert all these shapefiles to MapInfo with ogr2ogr?

I know how I can convert one file. 
And I can make a batch script writing a line for each file. 
But isn't there an easier way to convert all the files in a directory (and subdirectory).

Comment: It depends what operating system. Basically make a "for" loop, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7803/bulk-load-multiple-shapefiles-into-postgis/7806#7806

Comment: OS is Windows 7. I try this in the command prompt: for %f in *.shp; do ogr2ogr -f MapInfo File $f.tab. But that doesn't work. I get the error: 'Unable to open datasour '$f.tab' with the following drivers.....

Comment: This is how to do SHP to TAB: ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo File" %1.tab %1.shp. But unless OGR is able to recognize a PRJ file correctly, you easily end up with TAB files with the wrong coordsys built-in. I recommend using the built-in Universal Translator (scaled down FME), which can also process all the files you select. It allows you to select the correct coordsys.

Comment: I do indeed have problems with the right projection in MapInfo File. I try to include the right projection, but this doesn't work. The projection in de mapinfo file is set to non-earth (meters). Is it possible to include the correct projection with the ogr2ogr tool. I would like to put the command lines in another script. So I rather not use the Universal Translator.

Comment: Have you tried [OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/) library and it's command-line tools?

Comment: Is this not the same as FW Tools?  Following your link, it tells me to download "the latest FWTools kit"...

Comment: OGR is a part of FW Tools. You can run batch processing the way as @alexandre-neto has answered you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

On Windows, for the current and sub-directories under the current, try this command:

```
for /R %f in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo File" "%~dpnf.tab" "%f"
```

To briefly explain the [trickery of what is going on here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true), `%~dpnf.tab` uses the variable ***%f***, with which it adds the **d**river letter, **p**ath name (i.e., folder or directory), and extracts the file **n**ame (without the `.shp` file extension). Lastly, `.tab` is added immediately after the compound variable modifiers for the new extension.

So if you are in directory `C:\MyData`, and you have data in this directory, and sub-directories `C:\MyData\Region1` and `C:\MyData\Region1\City1`, any Shapefile (with `.shp` extension) will be processed, and a similar named file with `.tab` will created in the same directory.

Comment: Cool! This works! Many thanks for the answer :)

One more question: Is there also a way to refer to subdirectory and convert the files in another subdirectory. 

I have a containing various directories containting shapefiles. Such as: 
Netherlands\shape\provinceX
Netherlands\shape\provinceY
Netherlands\shape\provinceZ

And would like to convert this into these folders:
Netherlands\mapinfo\provinceX
Netherlands\mapinfo\provinceY
Netherlands\mapinfo\provinceZ

Thanks :)

Comment: I've updated the above for a recursive search, however I don't know how to do the extra logic to change "shape" to "mapinfo"; maybe find/ask on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Thanks again for your quick response. This was very helpful. I only need to copy the files to the right directory.

Comment: Note that Windows command line and batch file command differ: You have to double the percent `%f` to `%%f`. See http://ss64.com/nt/for.html for details.

Comment: This a great, is the a similar approach on a MAC

Answer (score 13):

For unix bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in *.mif # cycles through all files in directory (case-sensitive!)
do
    echo "converting file: $FILE..."
    FILENEW=`echo $FILE | sed "s/.mif/_new.shp/"` # replaces old filename
    ogr2ogr \
    -f "ESRI Shapefile" \
    "$FILENEW" "$FILE"
done
exit
```

If you're working in a *nix-based OS (ie Linux or OS X), there are some batch shell scripts that [clhenrik](https://github.com/clhenrick) developed [here](https://github.com/clhenrick/shell_scripts) (which the above is based on).

I'm working on a fork that makes some of the scripts a little more generic and provides a little more description on use.

---

Comment: This will cause an error if the filename contains spaces.

Comment: I believe this answer above works with spaces. most likely @JasonRDalton edited the old version :)

Answer (score 9):

As [Alex Markov](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/4728/alex-markov) said, the best way would be for you to use [OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs).

You will need to do a script, but a very simple one. Basicly if you are using windows, all you have to do is run the following code in the command line (inside de desired folder):

```
for %f in (*.tab) do ogr2ogr -f "KML" %~nf.kml %f
```

Check this site, all is explained here:

[http://www.processamentodigital.com.br/?p=2511](https://web.archive.org/web/20120521122640/http://www.processamentodigital.com.br/?p=2511)

Comment: I think you can also do: ogr2ogr -f "KML" {outfolder} {infolder}

Tip taken from http://underdark.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/batch-shapefile-clipping/

Comment: **NB** This reply came from a closely related question that referred to different file formats.

Comment: Hi, when I try this approach in Ubuntu e.g.  ogr2ogr -f "KML" {outfolder} {infolder} I get the error: 'ERROR 4: Failed to create KML file'. Any idea what might be going wrong here? I have built GDAL with KML support

Answer (score 8):

with python:

```
import os 

for a in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
   fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(a)
   os.system('ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" %s %s' % (a, fileName + '.tab'))
```

you can change `os.getcwd()` to your path where your files are located...

i hope it helps you

Comment: `for a in *.shp:` is a syntax error; you are thinking `from glob import glob; for a in glob('*.shp'):`

Comment: oh sorry, i have written it in wrong style. i have updated. @ Mike Toews thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a loop, you can simply name a directory as source and destination and ogr2ogr will convert any files in the source directory.
See here:
[Converting TAB to MIF / MIF to TAB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22349/converting-tab-to-mif-mif-to-tab/22352#22352)

Comment: Thanks! Can I refer from one parent directory to all the subdirs and converting all the files to other subdirs. 

Ihave:
Netherlands\shape\provinceX 
Netherlands\shape\provinceY 
Netherlands\shape\provinceZ
and so on...

And would like to convert this into these folders: Netherlands\mapinfo\provinceX 
Netherlands\mapinfo\provinceY 
Netherlands\mapinfo\provinceZ

I can write a line for each province, but can I also do it with one command

Comment: I havent't tried this, but I don't think that this is possible. You would need a loop wich handles the respective input and output directories. In this case it is probably easier to follow a python approach.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you need a for loop - see http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php for an explanation of how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Universal Translator in Mapinfo can handle multiple files. Go to the destination folder, select all shapefiles, define CRS for input and output. It should be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is refinement of Aragon's answer above.  It will only run ogr2ogr on .TAB or .tab files, and ignore other file types in the folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os 

for a in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
  fileName, ext = os.path.splitext(a)
  if ext.lower() == '.tab':
    print('ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" %s %s' % (a.replace(ext,
                           '.shp'), fileName + ext))
    os.system('ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" %s %s' % (a.replace(ext,
                           '.shp'), fileName + ext))
```