# Batch Convert MapInfo .TAB Files to .KML

Tags: mapinfo, convert, kml, batch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ogr2ogr convert all shapefiles in a directory](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/ogr2ogr-convert-all-shapefiles-in-a-directory)

As the title suggests, i have a few hundred .TAB files to convert to .KML.  This is likely to be a fairly irregular thing so FME (while brilliant!) is not really an option, and FW Tools doesn't appear to offer batch conversion, without possibly scripting the solution.  There there isnt a way in MapInfo/MapBasic to do this either.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

AM