# Converting .kml file to .tab (Map info) format

Tags: mapinfo, kml, mapbasic

If I have saved polygons as a (.kml) Google Earth File and I want to draw it in MapInfo, is there a tool to do this ?

If not, how can be it be made using MapBasic?

Comment: You can try Global Mapper software for this conversion directly OR convert it to .shp file and then convert .shp to .tab format with the help of QGIS

Answer (score 7):

The last few versions of MapInfo Pro can read KML files directly thru File > Open Universal Data.

With MapInfo Pro v2021, we added support for OGR Vector Files through the GDAL library. This adds another of reading KML/KMZ files into MapInfo Pro

Answer (score 2):

Why would you like to do it using MapBasic?
There are a range of conversion processes out there. For example, something like QGIS (http://www.qgis.org/) would be useful to do the conversions on a one-by-one basis. If you're looking for a batch / automated conversion (which it appears you are) you should really head to this thread:

[Batch Convert MapInfo .TAB Files to .KML](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25548/batch-convert-mapinfo-tab-files-to-kml)