# ogr2ogr clip all shapefiles in a directory

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr2ogr, clip

I am new to ogr2ogr. Does anyone know if it is possible to loop through all shapefiles in a directory, clip and output them into an identical directory with a suffix "_clipped"?

I saw this similar question about converting all files in a directory. Problem here is that using this method I overwrite all my files.
[Using ogr2ogr to convert all shapefiles in directory?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/ogr2ogr-convert-all-shapefiles-in-a-directory)

**EDIT:**

I want to make a .bat script to execute the code. This is how far I've come. It works if I output to the same folders as input, but I want it to output to some other folder. The user enters a new folder name, to where the clipped files will be saved.

Here is the returned errors:
Error 1: Failed to create file .shp file
Error 4: Failed to open shapefile *'correct path'*

--
set parent=%~dp0
set ogr2ogrPath="C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.16.1\bin\ogr2ogr.exe"

set /p inFolder=Enter the name of the root folder containing the shapefiles to clip:
set /p outFolder=Enter a new name for the folder to save the clipped files:
set /p xMin=Enter xMinCoord:
set /p yMin=Enter yMinCoord:
set /p xMax=Enter xMaxCoord:
set /p xMax=Enter yMaxCoord:

for /R %parent%%inFolder% %%f in (*.shp) do %ogr2ogrPath% -skipfailures -clipsrc xMin yMin xMax xMax %parent%%outFolder%\%%~nf.shp %%f

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Modifying the referenced answer, in the Windows command line:

```
for /R %f in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr "%~dpnf_clipped.shp" -clipsrc clipper.shp "%f"
```

You just add _clipped to the output. Note, this will also clip the clipping file, and work recursively, so it will also clip the shapefiles in sub-folders.

If you don't want it recursive:

```
for %f in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr "%~dpnf_clipped.shp" -clipsrc clipper.shp "%f"
```

To run it into a subfolder without changing names of the files, although it cannot create the folder, so an empty "clipped" folder needs to exist:

```
for %f in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr ".\clipped\%~nf.shp" -clipsrc clipper.shp "%f"
```

And finally for a different folder in the same path. So instead of "C:\data" to get it into "C:\clipped" you can do:

```
for %f in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr ".\..\clipped\%~nf.shp" -clipsrc clipper.shp "%f"
```

Like with the previous command, that folder needs to exist.

Comment: Note that Windows command line and batch file command differ: You have to double the percent `%f` to `%%f`. See http://ss64.com/nt/for.html for details.

Comment: Added that this was for the command line.

Comment: Yes, it will work, but I'd like it to output all files with file name unchanged, in an other folder with a different name. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: This is it! Thank you. All I was missing was adding the output folder first.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use Python? You could use some for cycle. I tried to write some concept here:

```
import os

wd = r"c:\your\working\dir"
os.chdir = wd
list_of_files = os.listdir(wd)

file_that_clips = "path_to_shapefile_that_clips_other"

for file in list_of_files:
    if file_to_clip[-3:] == "shp":                          # If file is a shapefile
        clipped_file = file_to_clip[:-4] + "_clipped.shp"   # New name for output
        os.system("ogr2ogr -clipsrclayer " + file_that_clips + " " + clipped_file + " " + file_to_clip)    # Execute cmd order
```

I'm not sure about the ogr2ogr Clip statement. But you could copy there yours.

Comment: Thanks, but I will try to keep it as simple as possible, so I'll look for a solution to be executed in shell first.