# Convert multiple .xml files in one dir to geopackages into another dir with ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr, citygml

Update: I did find the referenced stack discussion but the difference here is:

- my question is referring to transform .XML to geopackage (not .shape to map info)
- I would like to include the specification of the driver
- I explicitly ask for storing the files into another folder than the resource folder.

---

I have successfully converted a .xml file to a geopackage with the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG "path\to\LoD1.gpkg" GMLAS:"path\to\LoD1.xml" -oo REMOVE_UNUSED_FIELDS=YES
```

However, I somehow cannot make it to work on a full directory. What I would like is transform all files in one folder into geopackages storing it in another folder.

What I tried is:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" "path\to\outputfolder" GMLAS:"path\to\inputfolder" -oo REMOVE_UNUSED_FIELDS=YES
```

But this throws the error:

Unable to open datasource `GMLAS:path\to\inputfolder' with the following drivers. (then a list of all the driver follows, including GMLAS).

What do I need to change on the command?

Comment: on windows some trickery is required https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/25376/276

Comment: The referenced answer I have found before but didn't answer my question. For example, it doesn't answer how to specify the driver. Further, shapefiles are a different format than XML, and, as far as I have seen, it is not specifying a new directory. Therefore I would be glad if the question would be reopened.

Comment: The shapefile driver can read a directory of shapefiles, and then each shapefile in the directory is seen as a separate layer. It is documented https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html "Normally the OGR Shapefile driver treats a whole directory of shapefiles as a dataset, and a single shapefile within that directory as a layer. In this case the directory name should be used as the dataset name." GML driver does not behave like this,

Answer (score 2):

This question does not deal with GIS really. It is about generic computing and how to run a command line program in a FOR loop.

If you have input GML files in a directory `c:\data\gml1` and you want to store the GeoPackages into directory `c:\data\gml2\` run something like this:

```
for %f in (c:\data\gml1\*.gml) do ogr2ogr -f gpkg "c:\data\gml2\%~nf.gpkg" "GMLAS:%f"
```

- Reads the filenames from the input directory into variable %f
- Opens one by one the file %f with the GMLAS: driver
- Uses -gpkg driver for output
- Stores the output into the output directory, uses the "name" part of the input file name together with .gpkg extension

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right that this is more a question on how to use the command line in Windows, I wasn't aware of it. I still think, this question will help others who want to work with ogr2ogr.
Unfortunately I am not able to run it, and I think I have a problem with the paths , as they have spaces,  - ,  : , and German signs (like ä)).
I will need to dig here deeper what it is with the paths